# notification system in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am working on a laravel app where i have a user(organizer) who post an event ,and other users can comment on this event .

---

I am trying to make notifications system in laravel 8  between the organizer and the users when commenting on these event !
but i get this error **(Call to a member function notify() on null)**.

---

**This is my class :**

---

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewCommentPosted extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $user;
    protected $event;

    public function __construct($user, $event)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->event = $event;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user' => $this->user->name,
            'eventTitle' => $this->event->title,
            'eventId' => $this->event->id
        ];
    }
```

**This is storefunction() in my controller :**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Notifications\NewCommentPosted;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
   

    public function store(Event $event)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'content' => 'required|min:5'
        ]);
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->content = request('content');
        $comment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $event->comments()->save($comment);
    
        $event->user->notify(new NewCommentPosted(auth()->user(), $event));
    
        return redirect()->route('events.show', [$event->id, $event->title]);
    }
```

Any help please !!?